# Benefit from using boost::optional in the following usecase?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

This is a very fundamental question. Is there any benefit in using boost::optional in the following scenario:

```
int somefunction(boost::optional<const Param&> value = getDefaultParam()){
    return value->dosomething();
}
```

or

```
int somefunction(boost::optional<const Param&> value){
    if (!value) 
            value = getDefaultParam();
    return value->dosomething();
}
```

as opposed to just doing this:

```
int somefunction(const Param& value = getDefaultParam()){
    return value.dosomething();
}
```

This is for the specific case where I know that I am initializing the Param object to a default value. Can there be any benefit of using a boost::optional on Param to the API or the client of the API ?

Comment: No. Just do the last one.

Comment: What does `getDefaultParam` return?  If it returns a `Param`, #2 is not going to be very correct (I am unsure if `boost` would let it compile, but it won't work).  Generally a `boost::optional<const Param&>` can be replaced with a `Param const*`, as `boost::optional<const&>` is a non-owning reseatable nullable reference... and so is `Param const*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this is bad:

```
int somefunction(boost::optional<const Param&> value = getDefaultParam()){
    return value->dosomething();
}
```

`someFunction` could be called with `boost::none`, in which case attempting to access it's value will throw an exception.

Second, if you have a `boost::optional<const Param&>`, an API is provided to get its value or a default:

```
boost::optional<const Param&> value = ...;
value.value_or(getDefaultParam()).doSomething();
```

EDIT: On this simple case, it may not be worth bringing in `optional`. If you do something like this:

```
int someFunc(const Param& value = getDefaultParam())
{
    return value.doSomething();
}

// Elsewhere...
int x = someCondition ? someFunc(abc) : someFunc();
```

There isn't really a point for `optional` here. Of course, something simple like this, there may not be much need for `someFunc` either:

```
int x = (someCondition ? abc : getDefaultParam()).doSomething();
```

However, if you need longer-term storage/tracking of whether a value is available or not, then `boost::optional` might be appropriate.